# source .bash_profile is not working in shell script. How can i do?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to use 'source ~/.bash_profile' command from a shell script. But this doesn't work. My script is like this: 
test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I use many ways to run the script `./test.sh`, `bash test.sh` and `sh test.sh`. if run with `. /test.sh` it is work. This is the running the script? This is the right way to run the installation script?

btw I also test by changing script with `. ~/.bash_profile`, `bash ~/.bash_profile`, `sh ~/.bash_profile`, `bash -c '~/.bash_profile'`.
What is the 'source' problem in shell script. Please explain me what is the right way? How can i source .bash_profile in the script. Thank to everyone!!

Comment: make sure the file is actually there: `ls -l ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @shreyasminocha Probably not worth submitting edits on questions which are going to be deleted anyway. You are creating more noise by bumping this back onto the start page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have not changed the access to make the script executable?

```
   chmod +x test.sh
```

Only then can you run it. Hope this helps (Let me know if I misunderstood)

Comment: So in short write a script then make it executable like I said and then run it like ./test.sh

Answer (score 0):

When you start a bash script you are starting a new shell, so you are running source in a subshell and not your shell where you are issuing command.

It works when you start it with `. /test.sh` because that is the same as doing `source /test.sh` you are starting the commands from script in the same shell and not in a subshell.